# Output JSON from Bash script

Tags: json, bash

So I have a `bash` script which outputs details on servers. The problem is that I need the output to be `JSON`. What is the best way to go about this? Here is the bash script:

```
# Get hostname
hostname=`hostname -A` 2> /dev/null

# Get distro
distro=`python -c 'import platform ; print platform.linux_distribution()[0] + " " +        platform.linux_distribution()[1]'` 2> /dev/null

# Get uptime
if [ -f "/proc/uptime" ]; then
uptime=`cat /proc/uptime`
uptime=${uptime%%.*}
seconds=$(( uptime%60 ))
minutes=$(( uptime/60%60 ))
hours=$(( uptime/60/60%24 ))
days=$(( uptime/60/60/24 ))
uptime="$days days, $hours hours, $minutes minutes, $seconds seconds"
else
uptime=""
fi

echo $hostname
echo $distro
echo $uptime
```

So the output I want is something like:

```
{"hostname":"server.domain.com", "distro":"CentOS 6.3", "uptime":"5 days, 22 hours, 1 minutes, 41 seconds"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this all from Python? I mean, you're using it anyway, and Python is can easily determine the hostname, read the uptime, and generate the JSON you want.

Comment: See [this newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470049/build-a-json-string-with-bash-variables) but which has  better quality answers.
Note that building a valid JSON requires properly handing special characters in the input like `"` and `\n`, and simple string concatenation does not guarantee that.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you only need to output a small JSON, use `printf`:

```
printf '{"hostname":"%s","distro":"%s","uptime":"%s"}\n' "$hostname" "$distro" "$uptime"
```

Or if you need to produce a larger JSON, use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) as explained by [leandro-mora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4227051/leandro-mora). If you use the here-doc solution, please be sure to upvote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33222745/751863):

```
cat <<EOF > /your/path/myjson.json
{"id" : "$my_id"}
EOF
```

---

Some of the more recent distros, have a file called: `/etc/lsb-release` or similar name (`cat /etc/*release`). Therefore, you could *possibly* do away with dependency your on Python:

```
distro=$(awk -F= 'END { print $2 }' /etc/lsb-release)
```

An aside, you should probably do away with using backticks. They're a bit old fashioned.

Comment: `printf` would be a bit cleaner: `printf '{"hostname":"%s","distro":"%s","uptime":"%s"}\n' "$hostname" "$distro" "$uptime"`

Comment: Upvote for printf since it seems to work on BSDs as well. At least in OSX, `echo` doesn't have the '-e' option from what I can see in the manual.

Comment: Upvoted for the comment re backticks.  Not only are they old-fashioned , but they are hard to read, and most importantly non-nestable.  Nested command-substitution is an occasionaly used but very powerful mechanism.

Comment: `echo -e` should generally Not Be Used. The POSIX sh specification disallows it (or, rather, permits it to have no behavior other than printing `-e` on stdout -- unlike most bashisms, this one doesn't just extend the standard but actively breaks it); and bash may or may not honor it depending on the active runtime configuration; see [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819) on [unix.se], and/or the [POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which itself recommends using `printf` instead!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed. I have removed the `echo -e` solution. Never expected this answer to get much attention... or any of my answers for that matter..

Answer (score 58):

I find it much more easy to create the json using `cat`:

```
cat <<EOF > /your/path/myjson.json
{"id" : "$my_id"}
EOF
```

Comment: This is only a complete solution if no JSON-encoding is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a bash-ninja at all, but I wrote a solution, that works perfectly for me. So, I decided [to share it](https://gist.github.com/Jimilian/c3a2d8bb6df1b8ca64d02a10d97f510b) with community.

First of all, I created a bash script called `json.sh`

```
arr=();

while read x y; 
do 
    arr=("${arr[@]}" $x $y)
done

vars=(${arr[@]})
len=${#arr[@]}

printf "{"
for (( i=0; i<len; i+=2 ))
do
    printf "\"${vars[i]}\": ${vars[i+1]}"
    if [ $i -lt $((len-2)) ] ; then
        printf ", "
    fi
done
printf "}"
echo
```

And now I can easily execute it:

```
$ echo key1 1 key2 2 key3 3 | ./json.sh
{"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jimilian script was very helpful for me. I changed it a bit to send data to [zabbix auto discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery)

```
arr=()

while read x y;
do
    arr=("${arr[@]}" $x $y)
done

vars=(${arr[@]})
len=${#arr[@]}

printf "{\n"
printf "\t"data":[\n"

for (( i=0; i<len; i+=2 ))
do
     printf "\t{  "{#VAL1}":\"${vars[i]}\",\t"{#VAL2}":\"${vars[i+1]}\"  }"

    if [ $i -lt $((len-2)) ] ; then
        printf ",\n"
    fi
done
printf "\n"
printf "\t]\n"
printf "}\n"
echo
```

Output:

```
    $ echo "A 1 B 2 C 3 D 4 E 5" | ./testjson.sh
{
    data:[
    {  {#VAL1}:"A", {#VAL2}:"1"  },
    {  {#VAL1}:"B", {#VAL2}:"2"  },
    {  {#VAL1}:"C", {#VAL2}:"3"  },
    {  {#VAL1}:"D", {#VAL2}:"4"  },
    {  {#VAL1}:"E", {#VAL2}:"5"  }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tiny program in Go, [json_encode](https://github.com/fedir/json_encode). It works pretty good for such cases:

```
$ ./getDistro.sh | json_encode
["my.dev","Ubuntu 17.10","4 days, 2 hours, 21 minutes, 17 seconds"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data=$(echo  " BUILD_NUMBER : ${BUILD_NUMBER} , BUILD_ID : ${BUILD_ID} , JOB_NAME : ${JOB_NAME} " | sed 's/ /"/g')

output => data="BUILD_NUMBER":"29","BUILD_ID":"29","JOB_NAME":"OSM_LOG_ANA"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than just posting the code, it would be beneficial to elaborate on it a bit. Try explaining what is wrong with the code in the question, and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the subject line, if you were to needing to to get a tab separated output from any command line and needed it to be formatted as a JSON list of lists, you can do the following:

```
echo <tsv_string> | python3 -c "import sys,json; print(json.dumps([row.split('\t') for row in sys.stdin.read().splitlines() if True]))
```

For example, to get a zfs list output as json:

```
zfs list -Hpr -o name,creation,mountpoint,mounted | python3 -c "import sys,json; print(json.dumps([row.split('\t') for row in sys.stdin.read().splitlines() if True]))
```