# echo json over command line into file

Tags: json, linux, cmd, echo

I have a build tool which is creating a *versions.json* file injected with a `json` format string.

Initially I was thinking of just injecting the json via an echo, something like below.

```
json = {"commit_id": "b8f2b8b", "environment": "test", "tags_at_commit": "sometags", "project": "someproject", "current_date": "09/10/2014", "version": "someversion"}

echo -e json > versions.jso
```

However the `echo` seems to escape out all of the quote marks so my file will end up something like this:

```
{commit_id: b8f2b8b, environment: test, tags_at_commit: somereleasetags, project: someproject, current_date: 09/10/2014, version: someproject}
```

This unfortunately is not valid JSON.

Comment: `cat json > versions.json`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To preserve double quotes you need to surround your variable in single quotes, like so:

```
json='{"commit_id": "b8f2b8b", "environment": "test", "tags_at_commit": "sometags", "project": "someproject", "current_date": "09/10/2014", "version": "someversion"}'
echo "$json" > versions.json
```

Take into account that this method will not display variables correctly, but instead print the literal `$variable`.

If you need to print variables, use the `cat << EOF` construct, which utilizes the Here Document redirection built into Bash. See `man bash` and search for "here document" for more information.

Example:

```
commit="b8f2b8b"
environment="test"
...etc

cat << EOF > /versions.json
{"commit_id": "$commit", "environment": "$environment", "tags_at_commit": "$tags", "project": "$project", "current_date": "$date", "version": "$version"}
EOF
```

If you're looking for a more advanced json processing tool that works very well with bash, I'd recommend [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

Comment: what if the json contains an array. like for ex:

{ "a" : "test", "b": ["test1","test2"] }

how can i achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524437/output-json-from-bash-script/12524510 migt help also

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables in between you can quote does this `'"'$variable'"'`. Below is the date example.

```
echo {'"date"' : '"'$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")'"'} > cron_checkpoint.json
```