# How to write JSON file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pm2

I'd like to write a JSON file using BASH but it seem's not working well..

My code :

```
sudo echo -e "Name of your app?\n"
sudo read appname
sudo cat "{apps:[{name:\"${appname}\",script:\"./cms/bin/www\",watch:false}]}" > process.json
```

Issue : `-bash: process.json: Permission denied`

Comment: have you checked you have permission to create a file at specified location ?

Comment: `sudo echo` and `sudo read` on the first two lines look completely pointless to me

Comment: When I do `sudo vim process.json` it works...

Comment: `vim` opens the file; with `> process.json`, the *shell* opens the file before `sudo` actually runs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output JSON from Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524437/608639)

Answer (score 33):

Generally speaking, don't do this. Use a tool that already knows how to quote values correctly, like `jq`:

```
jq -n --arg appname "$appname" '{apps: [ {name: $appname, script: "./cms/bin/www", watch: false}]}' > process.json
```

That said, your immediate issues is that `sudo` only applies the command, not the redirection. One workaround is to use `tee` to write to the file instead.

```
echo '{...}' | sudo tee process.json > /dev/null
```

Comment: Cannot make it an edit because that requires at least 6 characters, but the backtick after `false}]}` should be replaced with standard tick to work properly:
`jq -n --arg appname "$appname" '{apps: [ {name: $appname, script: "./cms/bin/www", watch: false}]}' > process.json
`

Comment: Thank you, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 12):

To output text, use `echo` rather than `cat` (which outputs data from files or streams).

Aside from that, you will also have to escape the double-quotes inside your text if you want them to appear in the result.

```
echo -e "Name of your app?\n"
read appname
echo "{apps:[{name:\"${appname}\",script:\"./cms/bin/www\",watch:false}]}" > process.json
```

If you need to process more than just a simple line, I second @chepner's suggestion to use a JSON tool such as `jq`.

Your `-bash: process.json: Permission denied` comes from the fact you cannot write to the `process.json` file. If the file does not exist, check that your user has write permissions on the directory. If it exists, check that your user has write permissions on the file.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: @NoelHarris for what exactly? jq, bash, quoting in bash?