# How can I incrementally generate JSON calling jq from bash repeatedly?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Is there some accepted 'best practice' of generating JSON documents using bash and jq? I have a script to gather various data, and to make it easier to further process using other tools I'd like to output the data in JSON format. So I'm using jq to make sure all the quoting etc. gets done correctly, as recommended in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48470227/75652. However, I'm struggling with how to generate it piecemeal instead of one giant jq call at the end. E.g. something like

```
read foo <<<$(</path/to/some/oneliner/file)
jq -n --arg f $foo '{foo: $f}'

bar=$(some_command)
jq -n --arg b $bar '{bar: $b}'
```

Will generate two separate objects (which can be processed with tools that support various more or less informal "JSON streaming" formats, including jq) whereas I'd want a single object, something like

```
{ "foo": SOMETHING, "bar": SOMETHING_ELSE }
```

but I can't do that with multiple jq calls as jq will complain that the incomplete JSON is malformed.

And to further add some complexity, in some cases I need to generate nested JSON structures. In another language like python I'd just put all the data in a set of nested dictionaries and then dump it to JSON in the end, but nested dictionaries in bash seem very tedious..

Comment: And to further add some complexity, in some cases I need to generate nested JSON structures. What is an example for that?

Comment: IMO shell is not a good choice for dealing with any serialized data formats. Yes we have tools like `jq` and `xmllint`, but they are cumbersome to use outside of very basic situations.

Comment: `jq -n --arg f "$foo" --arg b "$bar" '{foo: $f, bar: $b}'`?

Comment: *nested dictionaries in bash seem very tedious* Especially since bash only has one level associative arrays.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is always a good first stop before coming here; it would have pointed out the quoting bugs.

Comment: "Piecemeal instead of one giant call at the end" is generally counterproductive. The more distinct external processes you call the more overhead you're eating in spinning up those processes. More efficient to minimize their number, or -- ideally -- have only one.

Comment: (The same thing is also true of embedding awk in bash: If you can move a whole loop into awk instead of having bash call awk a separate time each time it goes through a loop, that's _vastly_ faster, typically several orders of magnitude; same thing is true for jq).

Comment: @Charles-Duffy : shellcheck is indeed an excellent tool that I frequently use. In this case however I was referring to quoting in json, which is why the --arg dance with jq is preferred to just echoing json directly from bash.

Comment: @janneb The bug he's referring to is not quoting the expansions of `$foo` and `$bar` in your `jq` invocations. See my earlier comment for the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

When reaching some complexity (or when I need to externally process some of the data between transformations) I typically end up using something along the lines of

```sh
jq --slurpfile foo <(
  
  # first inner shell script
  read foo <<<$(</path/to/some/oneliner/file)
  jq -n --arg f $foo '{foo: $f}'

) --slurpfile bar <(

  # second inner shell script
  bar=$(some_command)
  jq -n --arg b $bar '{bar: $b}'

) -n '$foo[0] + $bar[0]'
```

That way, the outermost jq call may still have a 'real' input on its own, and the inner calls are fairly maintainable with all bash variables in scope.

Comment: It needs to be `--arg f "$foo"` _with the quotes_. Likewise `--arg b "$bar"`.

Comment: Also some versions of bash can misbehave on account of `<<<$var` instead of `<<<"$var"`, though this is fixed in current releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can save and process intermediary JSON for the next jq command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r foo <a.txt

json="$(jq -n --arg f "$foo" '{foo: $f}')"


bar="$(pwd)"
jq -n --arg b "$bar" "$json"'+{bar: $b}'

# or alternatively
jq --arg b "$bar" '.bar=$b' <<<"$json"
```

Comment: _grumbles about `$(pwd)` in place of `$PWD`_

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it was for illustrative purpose only having a command to produce something reasonably predictable and simple. Sure `$PWD` would be largely preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The Q makes it seem that `$foo` and `$bar` can be pre-computed,
in which case you can use as a model:

```
jq -n --arg f "$foo" --arg b "$bar" '.foo = $f | .bar = $b'
```

Of course if the value of $foo is very large, it would be better to
make those values available to jq using a file-oriented command-line
option, such as `--slurpfile`.

If the computation of some of the values depends on very
large files, then invoking jq several times might make sense.  In that
case, making N calls to jq to marshal the values, then making one
extra call to assemble them into a single JSON object (perhaps using
'jq -s add') seems very reasonable.

An alternative along the lines suggested in the title of the Q would
be to create a pipeline of calls to jq, e.g.:

```
  jq -n --argfile f <(some nasty stuff) '.foo = $f' |
    jq  --argfile b <(some more nasty stuff) '.bar = $b' | ...
```

Finally, if $bar depends on $foo in some way, then if that dependence
can be expressed in a jq program, you could read in the underlying
values in one invocation of jq, using a more complex jq program.

Comment: The jq manual discourages the use of `--argfile`